# Increase top position of element on scroll until height is reached (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two containers set up on a page, the first and second. The second is after the first container.

I'm trying to write a jQuery function that upon reaching the end of the first container, on scroll, it changes the top position of the second container (negative top position) so it feels as if the second container is being scrolled up and over the first container.

I have the following so far, which is doing a few things to get me started. Firstly, on scroll, I know when I reach the bottom of the first container and when the trigger should happen to begin scrolling the second container up. But then, I am not very sure how to get the top position to negatively increment as I scroll.

Any help?

```
function caseStudyScroll() {

    var secondContainerHeight = $('.second-container').height();

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(document).height() - secondContainerHeight <= ($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop())) {
            var windowScroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        } else {

        }
    });
}
caseStudyScroll();
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using jQuery to handle the scrolling, you could use CSS transitions when you hit the trigger. When you hit the trigger, add a class/id that changes its top position by whatever amount puts it where you need. In the id/class of the second container, put the following:

```
-webkit-transition: top 1s;
transition: top 1s;
```

This will move the container to the new position in one second.

Hope that helps!

EDIT: Now that I think about it, I may have misunderstood your question. Do you want this to happen constantly, while scrolling up? That is, you want your second container to stay on the page while you scroll past the first one? In that case, changing the position to fixed in a similar method should work.

Comment: Yes, your edit is correct (thanks!) so it is set to fix (the second container) and offset from the bottom the height of itself, but when you scroll to the bottom I need it to scroll up (ie. adjust the negative bottom offset up and down as you scroll)

Comment: @braw So, you want to change its position once you reach a specific point in the page, or constantly?

Comment: Probably not too dissimilar to: http://jsfiddle.net/94xjdnqx/2/ but instead of the first container changing to the top position to make it seem as if it's the second container that is scrolling over, I'd like the second container to move over the first container when you reach the bottom, as you scroll. The jsFiddle is generally fine but it jumps and bounces a lot and doesn't reset the position to 0.

Comment: That fiddle doesn't seem to work all that well. The first container just disappeared when I scrolled. But If all you want is to have one container cover another, why not use a `z-index`? Just assign each container a `z-index` in it's respective class or id, and whichever one should be on top should have a higher index.